# Why does this java code not give an "is already defined " error?

Tags: java

Why does this java code not give an already defined error for y?
I can understand why, because it is in a loop. But it does not seem logical.

```java
class AlreadyDefined 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //int y = 0; //-- enable this for already defined error 
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
            int y = i; //not already defined 
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this code it results in an error:

```java
class AlreadyDefined 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int y = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
            int y = i; //already defined 
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are defining a second variable `y` inside the for loop... Just remove the `int` before it and write `y = i;` in the loop instead of `int y = i;`. I have a question (instead of an answer): Why do you create a variable that always gets the value of the loop counter variable?

Comment: Yes, but because of the loop a second y gets defined?

Comment: In the scope of the loop, you will have two y variable. It seems logical that it could not be allowed.

Comment: Do you want to use `y` inside the loop or do you want to have another (newly defined) variable in the scope of **each iteration**? Variables defined in an outer scope are available in an inner scope, but not the other way round.

Comment: If I follow your words, this must also be correct, but it is not: 

```
class AlreadyDefined 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Object x = new Object();
  int y = 0; 
  int y = 2; //gives error
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You cannot define the same variable twice in the same scope. The scope of your `for` loop occurs inside the method's scope, so `y` is already defined.

Long answer: This is a misunderstanding of variable scope. I'll try to explain:

```
class AlreadyDefined // begin class scope
{

    public static void main(String[] args){ // begin method scope

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ // begin loop scope. 
            /// This scope also includes variables from method scope
            int y = i; 
            System.out.println(i);
        } // end loop scope

    } // end method scope

} // end class scope
```

I labeled the respective scopes in the above code and where they begin and end.

In the above example, once the `for` loop ends, `int y` goes out of scope and can no longer be referenced. So after `end loop scope`, `System.out.println(y)` will fail, as `y` no longer exists.

In the second example, `y` already exists in method scope. You cannot redefine a variable with the same name in a "child" scope, which is why your second example fails.

There is one exception to this, however. You may define a variable with an identical name to one defined in class scope. So this would work:

```
class AlreadyDefined // begin class scope
{
    static int y = 0; // Defining variable with identical name.

    public static void main(String[] args){ // begin method scope

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ // begin loop scope
            int y = i; // This still works
            System.out.println(i);
        } // end loop scope

    } // end method scope

} // end class scope
```

For class scope, if there is an identically named variable in method scope, you must qualify it with `this`. So to reference the class scoped `y` variable inside `main`, you would use `this.y`. This is why you will commonly see variables assigned in constructors and setters like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    int property

    public SomeClass(int property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public void setProperty(int property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

Another example:

```
    public void setProperty(int property) {
       property = property;
    }
```

If you were to do this, this would have no effect, as you did not specify `this.property`. You'd simply be setting the value of property to itself.

Comment: I suppose the main confusion is how loop scope works. @Douma thought that the loop scope is created at the start of 1st iteration and then each iteration of the loop is executed inside the same scope, that closes after the last iteration. If it would be true, then yes, `int y = i;` inside the loop would fail on the 2nd iteration. But it is not how loop scope works. Loop scope is created at the beginning of **each** iteration and ends at the end of each iteration. So, if we would "expand" the loop, then `int y = i;` is defined in "sibling scopes", that is totally allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring y twice. Once outside the loop *int y = 0;* and once inside the loop *int y = i;*.

You should **replace int y = i; with y=i;**. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I understand why it fails.. but why does loading `int y = i; ` 5 times not fail in the loop?

Comment: Because in loop it is declared only once.

Comment: @Douma because every time System.out.println(i); executes, the block finishes and your y variable comes out of scope, then the block executes again as a new scope every time.

Comment: I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First declared `y` variable covers a broader scope including your for loop block. So it is visible inside for loop already. Because of this, redefining it inside for loop throws compilation error

```
class AlreadyDefined 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int y = 0; //this variable is global in aspect to your for loop
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        int y = i; //your y variable is visible in this for loop block
                   //so redefining it would throw a compiler error
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
```

So if you really want to use variable `y`, then don't define it again, and remove the `int` type before it.

Comment: `y` is not a global variable. It is local to the method, `main`

Comment: you're right. I meant covering a broader scope. I'll edit my answer.